# Another Javascript undefined error

Tags: javascript

Another undefined error that I cant seem to get my head around. 
When I run the code my results include a undefined line:

```
No fault 06:44:46
Pkey 1 undefined 06:44:44
Pkey 1 Left 06:44:37
No fault Feb 09 12:28
Pkey 1 undefined Feb 09 12:28
Pkey 1 Right Feb 09 12:28
```

Please could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
var a=p1.value;
var le=p9.value;
var re=p10.value;
if (le==true) {
            var x = " Left";
}
else if (re==true) {
            var x = " Right";

if (a>0) {
            var y = "Pkey"; 
            var result = y +" "+ a +" "+ x;
}
else if (a==0) {
            var result = "No fault"
return result;
```

Comment: `x` will be `undefined` if both `le` and `re` are anything other true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If neither the value of `le` or `re` evaluates to `true`, then `x` would be `undefined`.

As you only use `==` for comparison, remember that values like `0`, `null`, `empty string`, and `[]`all evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Thanks Kasper you were correct.

Answer (score -2):

The x should be declared before the statements.. and not inside the 'if' scopes

Comment: That's good coding style, but makes no difference from JavaScript's perspective.

Comment: Well it was worth to be down-voted because I had the opportunity to learn something new (actually js is not my native..) - just finished reading this related [issue about javascript variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope). Anyway as a developer in many programming languages it was the first think that catch my eyes and I think it might be helpful to stick the tradition of good coding style / readability code - especially when this is an enforcement in some other common programming languages.